# heightmap terrain collision OpenGL

Tags: c++, collision, terrain, heightmap

So I have rendered a terrain based on a heightmap. It's based on this tutorial that I followed - http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=8

Now I want to have my camera to be able to "walk" on the terrain and i'm unsure of how to actually do it. I have checked a lot of other examples and have gotten some hints for barycentric coordinates. But i'm unsure of how to implement it properly.

```
float Terrain::getY(int x, int z)
{

    //return
}

void Terrain::createTerrain()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Setup heightmap

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &uiVAOHeightmap); // Create one VAO
    glGenBuffers(1, &uiVBOHeightmapData); // One VBO for data
    glGenBuffers(1, &uiVBOIndices); // And finally one VBO for indices

    glBindVertexArray(uiVAOHeightmap);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBOHeightmapData);

    float fHeights[HM_SIZE_X*HM_SIZE_Y] =
    {
        10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f,
        5.0f, 5.0f,5.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f,
        5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f,
        5.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f,
        10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f,
        10.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f,
    };

    float fSizeX = 100.0f, fSizeZ = 100.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i<HM_SIZE_X*HM_SIZE_Y;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HM_SIZE_X*HM_SIZE_Y; j++)
        {
            float column = float(i%HM_SIZE_X), row = float(i / HM_SIZE_X);
            vHeightmapData[i] = glm::vec3(
                -fSizeX / 2 + fSizeX*column / float(HM_SIZE_X - 1), // X Coordinate
                fHeights[i],                                    // Y Coordinate (it's height)
                -fSizeZ / 2 + fSizeZ*row / float(HM_SIZE_Y - 1) // Z Coordinate
            );
        }
    }

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3)*HM_SIZE_X*HM_SIZE_Y, vHeightmapData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uiVBOIndices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBOIndices);
    int iIndices[] =
    {
        0, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5, 11, 36,
        6, 12, 7, 13, 8, 14, 9, 15, 10, 16, 11, 17, 36,
        12, 18, 13, 19, 14, 20, 15, 21, 16, 22, 17, 23, 36,
        18, 24, 19, 25, 20, 26, 21, 27, 22, 28, 23, 29, 36,
        24, 30, 25, 31, 26, 32, 27, 33, 28, 34, 29, 35
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(iIndices), iIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
    glPrimitiveRestartIndex(HM_SIZE_X*HM_SIZE_Y);
}
```

I also have a camera class where I call the getY function.

HM_SIZE_X and HM_SIZE_Y are both 6

Comment: for walking compute which triangle is under camera and compute perpendicular distance to it. If it is below it either step back your movement step or change height to `0`, To compute the distance you can exploit dot product of `triangle_normal` and `camera_position-ground_projected_camera_position`

Comment: Walking is just moving the camera. Looking around is rotating the camera (be aware of also rotate camera-up vector). What's your problem?

Comment: A simple solution would be to find which triangle you're standing on, calculate the height of the triangle at that point, and then limit your position to not go below that. The better solution is to start using one of the many free physics libraries/engines available to you.

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear with the question. The problem is not moving, the camera movement is implemented and the camera is able to "fly" around. My problem is to have it "walk" on the terrain, which is what i'm unsure of how to implement. I know that I have to get the Y value of the terrain and compare it with the Y value of the camera to decide if the camera is above or below the terrain. But i'm not sure how to implement it.